# How to tell mysql to scan just recent one million rows

Tags: mysql

I have a Myisam table with 15,000,000 rows, my current query is like this:

```
SELECT id, MATCH(title) AGAINST('$searchterm' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM news 
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('$searchterm' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

How can I create a query to tell Mysql to scan just recent one million rows (not whole table)?

Comment: what do you mean by "scan"?

Comment: I think Mysql can ignore part of table when running the query. In this case, I want Mysql act with my table, like a table with 1 million rows, not 15 million rows. I want Mysql ignore scanning 14 million rows when running the query and just scan the last 1 million rows.

Comment: A fulltext index always works on the whole table. You cannot prevent that. Are you concerned about the execution speed? A fulltext search is most efficient if your search term is rare (e.g. returns only a handful of rows), and can get very slow - compared to e.g. a simple full table search with `like` - if the search finds a large amount of rows. So depending on that and other requirements and conditions, you might need to adept your search strategy (and/or e.g. use a more specialized search system like solr, elasticsearch or similar).

Comment: With partitions maybe possible. Not sure.

Comment: Maybe with a timestamp column with index on it.

Comment: @DanielE. Fulltext indexes are not possible on partitioned tables - for the reason that they are designed to work only on the whole table.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as "Recent N rows" unless you have a date or timestamp column to define such a thing.